# writing to sql server from C#, no errors returned

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write to a database from c#:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    try
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=nesoi;Initial Catalog=SalesDWH;Integrated Security=True";

        // This creates an object with which you can execute sql
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [SalesDWH].[dbo].[PendingSpecimens]
                                                       ([Date Entered]
                                                       ,[Specimen ID]
                                                       ,[Test]
                                                       ,[Agency])
                                    VALUES (@DateEntered,@SpecimenID,@Test,@Agency)";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            // This is how you add a parameter to your sql command
            // This way you are protected against SQL injection attacks
            SqlParameter DateEntered = command.CreateParameter();
            DateEntered.ParameterName = "@DateEntered";
            DateEntered.Value = fields[0];
            command.Parameters.Add(DateEntered);

            SqlParameter SpecimenID = command.CreateParameter();
            SpecimenID.ParameterName = "@SpecimenID";
            SpecimenID.Value = fields[1];
            command.Parameters.Add(SpecimenID);

            SqlParameter Test = command.CreateParameter();
            Test.ParameterName = "@Test";
            Test.Value = fields[2];
            command.Parameters.Add(Test);

            SqlParameter Agency = command.CreateParameter();
            Agency.ParameterName = "@Agency";
            Agency.Value = fields[4];
            command.Parameters.Add(Agency);

            connection.Open();

            int someint=command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
        textBox1.Text = ee.ToString();
    }
```

In addition to no errors being returned, it has not written anything either!

What am I doing wrong?

I suspect that this line:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

is not working.

Mut I do not understand why

please help!

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns an int which is the number of rows affected, if it returns -1 if it was rolled back. You can check that. Also can you see the query in SQL profiler?

Comment: @iaimtomisbehave no it will not execute that line at all. it will not give me anything for the int. please see updated

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "will not execute that line"? Do you mean the debugger skips the line? If that is the case try to not use the debugger and output the integer value to your textBox1.

Comment: @I__: The value that you're getting back has no further use, it's probably being removed.  Try actually doing something with it to see what it really is.

Comment: use try cath (SqlExeption ex)

Comment: Try using SQL Query Profiler to see if the query is actually being executed. I always find this tool handy for these cases

Comment: Is fields[] a String array, or are you missing the .ToString()? Also is it on purpose that you skip the 3rd field?

Comment: @PostMan actually profiler doesnt show any query being exectued!

Comment: @JeremyThompson its already a string array

Comment: Just use a stored procedure dude ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=nesoi;Initial Catalog=SalesDWH;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    string queryString = "INSERT INTO SalesDWH.dbo.PendingSpecimens([Date Entered], [Specimen ID], Test, Agency) VALUES (" + fields[0] + ", " + fields[1] + ", " + fields[2] + ", " + fields[4] + ")";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I've noticed a couple of your answers, thanks for helping out. Two tips, this answer is prone to SQL Injection and if the fields are strings they'd need quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing the parentheses in the values clause?