# Why ExecuteNonQuery() returning -1 without any exception and without inserting the entry in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, exception, executenonquery

I have following function:

```
public Exception createTopic(Topic t)
{
    query = "insert into [DisData].[dbo].[discussions]([title],[description],[usrid],[dateadded],[desid],[likes],[shares],[visit],[replyto],[sno]) values(@title,@des,@uid,@dateadded,@did,@like,@share,@visit,@replyto,@sno)";
    try
    {
        com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", t.getTitle());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@des", t.getDescription());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", t.getUsrID());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateadded", t.getDate());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@did", t.getDesID());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@like", 0);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@share", 0);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visit", 0);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@replyto", t.getReplyToID());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sno", getDisCount() + 1);
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        res.Redirect("viewthread.aspx?id=" + t.getDesID());
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        con.Close(); return e;
    }
}
```

The connection string is defined in the constructor of containing class. The problem is that, whenever I try to execute this function, it executes without giving any exception, even not on Visual Studio Debugger Console, and also does not updates the database with new entry provided by the user. When I checked for return value of ExecuteNonQuery() it is returning -1. To me the code seem to be okay or may be I am missing something. Please help me to identify it.

I also tried to execute the query by removing all AddWithValue() statements and making the query pre-defined as

> insert into
>   [DisData].[dbo].discussions
>   values('Test','TestDes','TestUID','12-12-2012','sdsd',1,1,1,'sdsd',2)

But problem remains the same...

Comment: Catching exceptions and turning them into the function's return value seems distinctly odd.

Comment: The return value -1 means that a rollback has occurred. [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery)

Comment: which object value you are checking?

Comment: Try to execute your explicit query inside Management Studio and see what is has to say about it

Comment: @Schaliasos: So how to solve it??

Comment: @Steve: Ya I tried that and it executed nicely without any error.

Comment: Can you show your connection string?. Are you connected to the same database?

Comment: @Steve: Ya I am connected to same database. Here's the connection string "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DisData;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Have you tried to remove the [DisData].[dbo]. part from the Insert statement?

Comment: Try to execute the same query direct to the sql-server to see what's the error.

Comment: @Steve: Nothing happened. Still returning -1 after removing [DisData].[dbo]. part

Comment: @Schaliasos: Ya I tried that. Its executing finely in SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Last try, check if the parameter datatype in the AddWithValue correspond to the columns datatype. In particular usrid, desid and dateadded.

Comment: @Steve: the likes,shares, visit and sno are bigint and all others are nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: Please look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269850/writing-to-sql-server-from-c-no-errors-returned/9270200#comment11686518_9270200

Answer (score 0):

if you have started a transaction somewhere in the code, you should commit it using Transaction.Commit() method.
also I can see, you are using a long name for database table including database name, which should be avoided. check if the data is being inserted into DisData database and you are searching in another database...:)

Answer (score 0):

For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

More more detail read link [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)